# Adobe Fireworks CS4 and CS5 are very slow on a Mac

Tags: performance, osx-snow-leopard, adobe-fireworks

I have Adobe CS5 installed on my iMac.

I use Mac OS X 10.6.4

Most of the time i use Fireworks, that is very slow. It catches the screen for a few seconds, while i moving objects, manipulate with layers and do other stuff. Photoshop seems to be OK.

Anyone has such a problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to download any of the [Fireworks updates and fixes](http://www.adobe.com/support/fireworks/downloads_updaters.html). They seems to solve some of these known issues.